# Jenkins not able to build unity job

Tags: unity-game-engine, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Im trying to use jenkins for my unity build but jenkin never builds.

I'm invoking the unity 3d editor and using
-batchmode -nographics -quit -logFile "$WORKSPACE/editor.log" -buildTarget WebGL -projectPath "$WORKSPACE/KBTool/" -executedMethod Editor.Build.BuildWebGL.Build -env prod

The jenkins never builds the job, I have added:
-batchmode -nographics -quit -logFile "$WORKSPACE/editor.log" -buildTarget WebGL -projectPath "$WORKSPACE/KBTool/" -executedMethod Editor.Build.BuildWebGL.Build **"$WORKSPACE/bin"** -env prod

to specify a build path--- no dice

So in the meantime I build it locally using

"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.2.4f1\Editor\Unity.exe" -quit -batchmode -logFile stdout.log -projectPath "C:\Users\me\projects\Tool\KBTool" -executeMethod Editor.Build.BuildWebGL.Build -env prod

an upload my bin folder to my bitbucket repo

Any clues???